# Why it dont worked, and delete the comma in the curly braclets

Tags: java, windows, string, export

Hi Friends my code should delete commas, but commas between "" not and between curly bracelets, so the programm runs without a error but it delete also the commas between the curly bracelets. Here the code

```
package txtconverter;
import java.io.*;

public class converter{

 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
   try {

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                new FileReader("C:/Users/Sei_Erfolgreich/Desktop/convert.txt"));
                    String zeile;
        try {
            File newTextFile = new File("C:/Users/Sei_Erfolgreich/Desktop/convert3.txt");
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(newTextFile);
            while ((zeile = br.readLine()) != null) {
                zeile = zeile.replaceAll("\",\"", "\uffff").replaceAll(",", "").replaceAll("\uffff", "\",\"")
                        .replaceAll("\\},", "\\},");                        
                System.out.println(zeile);
                fw.write(zeile);
            }
             fw.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: what is the format of the file you are trying to manipulate?  if it is json, it may make more sense to use a json library to manipulate the text?  Also, I've removed the couchdb tag as this question isn't really about couchdb.

Comment: It is a couchdb export.... and it is a txt file